# Dell PowerConnect 5524 - SNMP OID for stack topology

Tags: switch, snmp, monitoring, stacking

I am looking for SNMP OIDs giving all information about the topology status. If directly connecting to the switch, I can find the following information :

```
    Unit  MAC Address        Software    Master    Uplink     Downlink   Status
    ----  -----------------  ----------  --------  ---------  ---------  -------
    1     d0:d0:d0:d0:d0:d0  4.1.0.16    Enabled   2          2          master
    2     d0:d0:d0:d0:d0:d0  4.1.0.16    Enabled   1          1          backup
    Topology is Ring
    Stack image auto synchronization is enabled

    Unit Unit Id After Reset
    ---- -------------------
     1            0
     2            0
```

I know that I can find the main information with the sub-tree :
.1.3.6.1.4.1.89.53.4

But, so far, I didn't find any OID to get the topology and the image synchronization.

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dell has the `rlstack.mib`.  It doesn't seem to exist online (anymore), but can be retrieved from the firmware on [Dell Support](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/powerconnect-5524/drivers), or I posted a copy on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/buzzsurfr/c01fbd1e6fcbd1174cc6cb7ef7647069).

Try using a snmpwalk on `.1.3.6.1.4.1.89.107` and see if you get any data.  If so, use the Gist or the full MIBs from the firmware to interpret.